# Loop through gallery images as links not console logging onclick, but becoming active via css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to loop through a gallery of gradient swathes, to highlight them so they can be edited back in the main image, but hitting a roadblock when clicking them to test they are working.  They are in a bootstrap row, as col-md-3's, and each swatch bg has an id of bg-gradient (row id is gallery). The below code works in as much as they become active via the css when hovered, but wont console log a test message on click.

html structure is a bootstrap row with id of "gallery", then 4 col-md-3's with id of "swatch", then the actual bg-gradient is what is being looped through. These become active on hover via css settings not via the JavaScript, but wont console log test message on click.

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTyvv.jpg)

Code:

```
 editSwatch() {
 let swatchs = document.querySelectorAll('swatch'),
 //let swatchs = document.getElementById('gallery'),
 links = swatchs.getElementsByTagName('bg-gradient'),
 i;
 for (i = 0; i < links.length; i += 1) {
 links[i].addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('click works') });
 }
```

Updated code as per comments below, but still exactly the same result, tried tagName on the links var and still same.

Seems to be finding the swatches, but not working on click.
Need to get that click working to carry on?

[image: Swatches]

Any tips welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no getElementsById() function as IDs are necessarily singular. You probably want the function getElementsByTagName() which will return an array of matching elements

Comment: Ah yes Ill change that thanks

Comment: Have updated everything as above, but still not getting console log message? Thankjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not keep same id for swatchs, also you can use below query selector with appropriate selector as parameter and loop through swatchs

`var swatchs= document.querySelectorAll(".swatchs");`

Comment: OK , and will change the id bg-graident to a class also.

Comment: yes you can so when you use querySelectorAll('.class') it will give you all nodes having that class.

Comment: Updated as above, have tried querySelector("gallery") and querySeletorAll("swatch") with it but still no log message? Thanks

Comment: can you please share your HTML code, also try using ".swatch" as it is class

Comment: var el = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch');
for(var i=0; i < el.length; i++){
    el[i].addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('click works') });
}

Comment: Yes code is in the image above  1 row class gallery  with 4x  col-md-3's class swatch and inside those the actual gradients class bg-gradient

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqy2bejr/1/ hope this will help

Comment: Hi must have been  something else because when I checked the lines one by one after commenting out, it all worked:      editSwatch(){
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch');
    for(var i=0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('click works');
    });
    }

Comment: Have got related question to this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034686/swap-bg-gradient-images-in-a-gallery-of-swatches   now swapping the bgs around from swatch to main div.

Answer (score 0):

Technically `onclick` needs to be a function instead. Currently you are passing the return value of `console.log()` which is `undefined` I believe. A function needs to be attached to `click` event in order to make it work.

You can use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) as the following:

```
links[i].addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('click works') });
```

Please see a working example how to attach a `click` event to a `<div>`:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('elem');
div.addEventListener('click', function () { console.log('hey hello'); });
```

```html
<div id="elem">Click me!</div>
```

I hope this helps!